# specifying trait constraint in scala

Tags: scala, traits

I want to test a number of stackable `traits` that extend from such one as this:

```
trait Layer{
  def write(s:String): String
}
```

Each one process the incoming string somehow and then passes it to the next layer, for example:

```
trait TimeStampLayer { 
  abstract override def write(s:String) = System.nanotime + super.write(s)
}
```

My idea was to write a base test class whith such a fixture:

```
abstract LayerTest { 

   type L

   val layer = new BaseLayer with L      // BaseLayer would be one that does nothing

}
```

where each test subclass would overwrite `L` with such an stackable `trait`.
This of course doesn't work, since there's no constraint on `L` to specify it's a trait. Quoting the compiler,

> type L needs to be a trait to be mixed in

I also thought of something like

```
abstract LayerTest[L <: Layer] {
  //...
}

class TimeStampLayerTest extends LayerTest[TimeStampLayer] {}
```

but I also can't constrain `L` to be a trait, or at least don't know how to

Is there any way to specify that a type is a trait?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't represent your Layers as functions `String => String` and use function composition?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is more fundamental than just missing a type constrait on `L` to specify it's a trait.
Even if you could do that, what should the compiler do? When using the `new` operator, the type must be fully known, but here `L` is an abstract type so `new BaseLayer with L` is entirely unknown at the point of you call `new`. There is thus no way for the compiler to know what to do here.

What you should do is simply to make `layer` abstract, and let the concrete sub-classes perform the instantation.

```
trait Layer{
  def write(s: String): String
}
trait TimeStampLayer extends Layer{ 
  abstract override def write(s: String) = System.nanoTime + super.write(s)
} 
trait BaseLayer extends Layer {
  def write(s: String) = s
}
abstract class LayerTest { 
   type L <: Layer
   val layer: L // Note that this is abstract
}
class MyTest extends LayerTest {
  class L extends BaseLayer with TimeStampLayer
  val layer = new L // We instantiate it here in the conrete test
}
```

Note that ease the pain I've used the fact that you can directly implement an abstract type by a concrete class of the same name (`class L extends ...`)

Comment: The `L` type is unknown at runtime but not at compile time, since it's indicated by `type`. My idea was that the compiler  could override the `createLayer` function for each subclass with the correct type. Mmmm, sounds like a job for a macro... I'll see if I can make it work!  Thanks for the `class L extends ...` trick, didn't know that one!

Comment: The problem is the same as trying to define something likre this: `trait Factory[T] { def create: T = new T }`. You could say that the compiler should override `create` for each subclass, but a fundamental property of generic classes or methods is that thei are compiled only once. Generics are in this aspect very different from C++ templates, which are instantiated at very use (making it possible to do exactly what you wnated to do here).

Comment: Implementing `create` as a macro won't help because `LayerTest` will still be compiled only once. What might work is to have `create` delegate the actual instantiation to a type class (a factory paramterized by the type to instantiate, passed implicitly) and provide a single implicit value of this factory, implemented as a macro.